# For any $\phi$, is $\phi$ self-adjoint on $E_{\lambda_1} \oplus E_{\lambda_2} \oplus...\oplus E_{\lambda_k}$ if $\phi$ stable on $T$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, adjoint-operators

> Let $E$ be a real finite dimensional inner product space, and $\phi :E \to E$
>   be any map having $k < n$ distinct eigenvalues $\{\lambda_i\}$. Let
>
> $$T = E_{\lambda_1} \oplus E_{\lambda_2} \oplus...\oplus
>  E_{\lambda_k}, \quad where \quad E_{\lambda_i} = \{x \in E | \phi(x) =
>  \lambda_i x\}, \quad i=1,...,k$$ .If $\phi$ is stable on $T$, then
>   $\phi |_{T}$ is self-adjoint.

I have realised today that for any linear map $\phi: E \to E$, the eigenvectors associated with different eigenvalues are linearly independent, so if we consider subspace of $E$ that is the direct product of the eigenspaces of eigenvalues of $\phi$, since this space is generated by the eigenvectors of $\phi$, I thuoght $\phi$ might be a self-adjoint in this space provided that $\phi(x) \in T \quad \forall x \in T$, i.e it is stable on $T$.

Therefore, it the above theorem that I have created true ? If not, why ? and is there any additional condition(s) that makes it true ?

Comment: By the way, $\phi$ is always stable on $T$, since it is by definition stable on every eigenspace. In fact your question is equivalent to "Is every diagonalisable operator self-adjoint?" to which the answer is : only if the eigenspaces are orthogonal to one another.

Comment: I agree, invariance is fundamental to the idea of an eigenspace.

Comment: @ArnaudD. Yes, you are right. In my mind there is an inner product, but I just forgot to add it to the question itself.Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $\phi:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_1=1$ and $\lambda_2=2$ and corresponding eigenspaces $E_1=\langle\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\\ \vdots \\0\end{pmatrix}\rangle$ and $E_2=\langle \begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\0\\ \vdots \\0\end{pmatrix}\rangle $, then $\phi|_{T}$ is representd by the matrix $$\begin{pmatrix}2&0\\1&1\end{pmatrix}$$ from which You can see $\phi|_{T}$ is not selfadjoint. If a linear mapping is selfadjoint eigenvectors to different eigenvalues have to be orthogonal as can be seen from $$\lambda_1(x_1,x_2)=(\phi x_1,x_2)=(x_1,\phi x_2)=\lambda_2(x_1,x_2)$$
where $\lambda_1\neq\lambda_2$ are eigenvalues with corresponding eigenvectors $x_1,x_2$.

Comment: I have so many "how" questions, I'm going to make a list.

Comment: I can see that from the way you have constructed $\phi$, it is stable on the direct product of its eigenspaces.

Comment: However, shouldn't the matrix have the entry $2$ for $a_{21}$ ?

Comment: Moreover, without using the fact that the matrix should be symetric, how can we show that $\phi$ is not self-adjoint on that space ?

Comment: By the way, $\phi$ should be defined on $\mathbb{R}^3$ to be consistent with your vector notation.

Comment: Yes, but for any $2<n$ the same example works if You fill up zeros, the entry $a_{21}=1$ is correct, it is easy to see that a mapping on a finite dimensional real vector space is selfadjoint if its matrix is symmetric($(x,\phi y)=x^{tr}Ay=(A^{tr}x)^{tr}y=(Ax)^{tr}y=(\phi x,y)$). Important is to see that selfadjoint linear mappings have orthogonal eigenvectors to different eigenvalues as proven in the last line and this gives You counterexamples in abundance.

Comment: Actually this is the only ingredient You need for what You want to show! Assume the sum $E_{\lambda_1}\oplus E_{\lambda_2}\oplus ... \oplus E_{\lambda_k}$ to be orthogonal, then the restriction of $\phi$ to this subspace is selfadjoint!

Comment: $(\sum_{j=1}^{k}x_j,\phi(\sum_{j=1}^k y_j))=(\sum_{j=1}^{k}x_j,\sum_{j=1}^{k}\lambda_j y_j)=\sum_{i,j=1}^k \delta_{i,j}\lambda_j(x_i,y_j)=\sum_{j=1}^k\lambda_j(x_j,y_j)=(\phi(\sum_{j=1}^{k}x_j),\sum_{j=1}^{k}y_j)$  $x_j,y_j\in E_{\lambda_j}$ and $x_i\perp y_j$ for $i\neq j$.

Comment: @Arnaud D. Thanks for the corrections, especially for the dots!

Comment: Dear Peter, in your answer you seem to provide a counterexample to my "thesis", but then you are commenting to that same answer as "[...]  then the restriction of ϕ to this subspace is selfadjoint! ", I'm not able follow you on this point.

Comment: Moreover, I'm confused about on which basis you did construct the matrix of $\phi$ because if it is on $E_1, E_2$, I do not know how did you get that matrix.

Comment: Your "thesis" is true $\textbf{if}$ You suppose the spaces $E_{\lambda_j}$ to be pairwise orthogonal, which is not the case in my counterexample. See also Arnaud D´s comment, orthogonality of eigenvectors to different eigenvalues is crucial here! The matrix is the one with respect to the standard basis. Evidently $\begin{pmatrix}2&0\\1&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}2&0\\1&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}2\\2\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: You´re welcome!